# Java Spring Form fields with HTML5 boolean attributes

Tags: java, forms, html, spring

I want to add the attributes `disabled`, `required`, and `autofocus` to Java Spring Forms 3.1. Thanks to [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232983/adding-html5-placeholder-attribute-to-spring-3-0-form-input-elements) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526409/extending-spring-form-tag-library-attributes) I found out how, but I can't get it to work for [boolean attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139786/what-does-it-mean-in-html-5-when-an-attribute-is-a-boolean-attribute).

We have a form utility lib that wraps Spring Form so that we can add labels and other things.

*Desired JSP:*

```
<formUtil:formInputBox ... autofocus="true" />
```

*Desired output HTML:*

```
<label>...<input type="text" ... autofocus /></label>
```

*This works* in our formUtil as JSP:include but doesn't use Spring:

```
<input type="text" ... <c:if test="${param.autofocus=='true'}">autofocus</c:if> />
```

*This doesn't work* in our formUtil Tag but uses Spring:

```
<form:input ... <c:if test="${autofocus==true}">autofocus</c:if> />
// Gives exception: `Unterminated &lt;form:input tag`.
```

**Question:**
How do I get the desired output with the desired input? I'd like to keep databinding etc in Spring so I don't want to role my own form fields.

**Note:**
Boolean attributes in HTML5 don't support boolean values so I can't have `autofocus=true`. It has to be just `autofocus` or `autofocus="autofocus"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't place a core tag inside a spring tag as you were trying

```
<form:input ... <c:if test="${autofocus==true}">autofocus</c:if> />
```

it is possible to insert jstl expressions in the value of a spring tag attribute, but they won't help you as html5 only checks if autofocus is present.

```
<s:set var="autofocusVal" value=""/>
<c:if test="${autofocus}">
    <s:set var="autofocusVal" value="autofocus"/>
</c:if>

<form:input autofocus="${autofocusVal}" />
```

but you could do something like:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${autofocus}">
        <form:input autofocus="autofocus" />
    </c:when>

    <c:otherwise>
         <form:input />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

which is really verbose and difficult to mantain, especially if you have several attributes you want to add.

Another crappy workaround could be set a data-xxx attribute to mark the tags with autofocus, and with javascript modify the html by adding the attribute autofocus where data-autofocus="true":

```
<form:input data-autofocus="${autofocus}" />
```

And the more elegant way of doing it (I can think of now) is to extend that tag with the attributes you want to add as it is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9891714/249699