# Spring forms:input HTML5 required attribute

Tags: html, forms, spring

I am using Spring forms and would like to use the HTML5 'required' attribute which Spring forms does not seem to support.

```
<form:input path="someinput" cssClass="required"/>
```

I cannot seem to do

```
<form:input path="someinput" cssClass="required" required="required"/>
```

as this is currently not supported by the Spring TLD.

It seems like I NEED to ditch spring forms if I want to use the full HTML5 spec

```
<input name="someinput" id="someinput" class="required" required="required"></input>
```

Does anyone know how I can implement the required field with spring forms 3.1.3.RELEASE?
Thanks!

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9891714/662250

Answer (score 3):

just add some jquery at the end of the page

```
    <html>
    <body>
            <form:input path="someinput" id="someinput"/>
    </body>
    <script>
            $("#someinput").attr('required', ''); 
    </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you just submit the form with default `commandName`, your approach is ok.
2. Better way to solve it: Write the form with spring-form and forget the required thing. Then find out what the real html spring-form generated for you. Write the html your own and add the required field.