# Using Vue.js in JSP, tags/directives conflict

Tags: javascript, java, vue.js, jsp

I'm trying to use Vue.js in a Java project where templates are rendered using JSP. I've been able to load the Vue library into the page, and to use it too.

This works:

```
<!-- code snippet from jsp -->
<select id="foobar"
    v-on:change="doSomething($event)"
    class="form-control form-control-lg">
        <option value="" selected>Do your choice...</option>
        <option value="foo">foo</option>
        <option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>
```

But, using vue directives along with, for example spring-form JSP tags:

```
<form:select
     path="something"
     v-on:change="blabla($event)"> <!-- also tried `@change` but still no success -->
     <form:options items="${yadayada}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
</form:select>
```

I get this error:

> The attribute prefix [v-on] does not correspond to any imported tag
>   library

I guess that the JSP engine thinks that `v-on` should be something from an external Java/JSP library, but that's not definitely the case. Is there any solution or workaround to use `v-on`, `v-bind` etc in such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It thinks the TLD for the tag doesn't allow dynamic attributes.

Even if it did, it wouldn't (necessarily) know where to put them in the HTML the tag renders: while `<form:select>` (likely) just renders an HTML `<select>` tag, there's no *guarantee* that a JSP tag would blindly render dynamic attributes where you wanted them.

You can *extend* a Spring tag (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/9891714/438992) but that isn't necessarily a straight-forward approach since you're doing more than just tacking on additional HTML--you're *inserting* HTML.

You could write your own custom tag that does the same rendering, but without care, you're likely to miss some functionality that might bite you later.

Or you can just write the HTML to match what the Spring tag renders--for simple use-cases this is the most direct path.